# SwiftUI ViewModel published property and binding

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui

My question is probably the result of a misunderstanding but I can't figure it out, so here it is:

When using a component like a TextField or any other component requiring a binding as input

```
TextField(title: StringProtocol, text: Binding<String>)
```

And a View with a ViewModel, I naturally thought that I could simply pass my ViewModel `@Published` properties as binding :

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject { 
     @Published var title: String
     @Published var text: String
}

// Now in my view
var body: some View {
    TextField(title: myViewModel.title, text: myViewModel.$text)
}
```

But I obviously can't since the publisher cannot act as binding. From my understanding, only a `@State` property can act like that but shouldn't all the `@State` properties live only in the View and not in the view model? Or could I do something like that :

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject { 
     @Published var title: String
     @State var text: String
}
```

And if I can't, how can I transfer the information to my ViewModel when my text is updated?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You were almost there. You just have to replace `myViewModel.$text` with `$myViewModel.text`.

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var title: String = "SwiftUI"
    
    @Published var text: String = ""
}

struct TextFieldView: View {
    
    @StateObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel = MyViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField(myViewModel.title, text: $myViewModel.text)
    }
}
```

---

`TextField` expects a `Binding` (for `text` parameter) and `StateObject` property wrapper takes care of creating bindings to `MyViewModel`'s properties using dynamic member lookup.

Comment: Can you elaborate how this works? How is $myViewModel.text able to satisfy @Binding?

Comment: @MegaManX You actually have 4 different spellings. First, you have $myViewModel which is is the whole struct as an ObservedObject. The second one is the myViewModel.text, which is simply a normal string to display on a view. For the third one, we have a binding. Since we want to bind our text to a textField we are using $myViewModel.text. The fourth one is myViewModel.$text. We are using this if we want the published values that this variable can give us. We could subscribe to this with combine.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@StateObject`, not `@ObservedObject` since you are instantiating it inside of the view?